# Solving equation Octave

Tags: octave

For some reason Octave cannot solve the following:

solve((sqrt(16-x^2))/2==1,x)

it gives: ans = {}(0x0)

But when I do this:

solve(sqrt(16-x^2)==2,x)

It finds the right answer

Can anybody explain what is going on?